# What does pom.xml do on github?

Tags: git, maven, github

Github is separate repository hosting supported by git, right? Then why are there `pom.xml` files in such projects like [this one](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht)? What are they doing there?

**UPDATE**

I know `pom.xml` is from Maven. But Maven has it's own repository [here](http://mvnrepository.com/). Why is this project on github while configured for maven?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the project is checked out it will be used by maven for dependency management, build management etc.

Answer (score 1):

Because such project are supposed to be built by using Maven.

http://maven.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

`pom.xml` is a descriptor file used by [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html), which is Java framework for handling project dependencies and managing the build process of Java projects (compiling, testing, etc). Also see the Mavens documentation about [pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Maven repositories has nothing to do with VCS like git. There're just released packages.